# ckeditor do not work when i add extraPlugins

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, fckeditor, ckfinder

i have uploaded **codesnippet** plugin inside **/ckeditor/plugins/** directory.

My config.js file codes are:

```
    CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config ) {
        config.toolbar = [
            { name: 'basic', items: [ 'Bold', 'Italic', 'Underline' ] },
            { name: 'font', items: [ 'Font' ] },
            { name: 'paragraph', items: [ 'NumberedList', 'BulletedList', 'Blockquote' ] },
            { name: 'links', items: [ 'Link', 'Unlink' ] },
            { name: 'insert', items: [ 'Image', 'Table', 'HorizontalRule' ] },
            { name: 'last', items: [ 'Maximize' ] }
        ];

        config.extraPlugins = 'codesnippet';
        config.format_tags = 'p;h1;h2;h3;pre';
        config.entities = false;
        config.removeDialogTabs = 'image:advanced;link:advanced;table:advanced';
        config.disableNativeSpellChecker = false;

    };
```

But when i add **config.extraPlugins = 'codesnippet';** line then editor do not work even i can't see textarea field.

And when i remove **config.extraPlugins = 'codesnippet';** line then editor works perfectly.

Comment: Voting to close, the problem has a very small potential audience that would benefit, this is a question of debugging without the specific error messages provided, and it is unlikely to be reproduced by other developers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [online builder](http://ckeditor.com/builder) to add the codesnippet plugin to your editor. Most probably your editor is missing dependencies.

Most plugins in CKEditor require some additional plugins to operate. If you download manually plugin A, there is a chance that you need to download dependencies for plugin A... and plugin B, which is required by plugin A. And sometimes you will need to download dependencies for plugin C, which was required by plugin B. Sounds like a nightmare, this is why we created online builder and why package managers exist.

Comment: I have added all dependencies plugin. I do not want to use builder. Please help.

Comment: Check developer console, there must be some errors logged. E.g. about missing plugins ;)

Comment: Yes there was missing dependencies Thanks